# Why does scikit-learn limit the regularization values for its SGD implementation?

Tags: scikit-learn, gradient-descent

The change was made by Olivier Grisel back in 2014 and can be seen [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/d0eb09b4b5229328b82f958e69fc64a05b874c36).

The first change limits the loss derivatives when they become too big, which makes sense to avoid divergence and numerical errors.

The second change is what I'm not sure I understand. During L2-regularization, when the weights would otherwise end up being negative due to the regularization step driving them below 0, they are instead held to 0.

Does anyone have any intuition about why they chose to do this? Can you mitigate potential oscillations around the minimum that way?